# ember js how to extend model

Tags: ember.js, model, ember-data

i am trying to extend a model but i can't figure out how to do it.

let say i want 2 different kinds of todo's in my [TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/emberjs/)
the first will add an url and the second will add an paragraph.(example)

this is what i had in mind:

```
Todos.Todo = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  isCompleted: DS.attr('boolean')
});

Todos.Todo.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Learn Ember.js',
    isCompleted: true,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: '...',
    isCompleted: false,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Profit!',
    isCompleted: false,
  }
];

Todos.TodoURL = Todos.Todo.extend({
    url: 'google.com',
});

Todos.TodoParagraph = Todos.Todo.extend({
    paragraph: 'Lorum...',
});
```

but that gives me `Assertion failed: Unable to find fixtures for model type Todos.TodoURL`

i have found the `reopen` function, but that doesn't provide the get and set function for my model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify your Fixtures or REST-Adapter to Todos.TodoURL and TodoParagraph. That wil work. Ember Data gets the URL to go to from the name of the class so when you retreive the TodoURL's it will call /todoUrl/.

Answer (score 2):

This happen because `ember-data` is trying to retrieve your fixtures using `Todos.TodoURL.FIXTURES` and `Todos.TodoParagraph.FIXTURES`. But when you extend the class, these properties aren't inherited. To make static methods and properties get inherited, you should use [reopenClass](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_reopenClass):

```
Todos.Todo.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Learn Ember.js',
      isCompleted: true,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: '...',
      isCompleted: false,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: 'Profit!',
      isCompleted: false,
    }
  ]
});
```

I hope it helps

Comment: it works, but it wasn't what i've been loking, i've decided to do this step in my data base and i will acces them via rest. thx for an great answer though